# Extract values from list with dicts

Tags: python, list, for-loop, nested-loops

I have a list with orders. Each order contains products and their prices.
What I want is to write the shortest script possible to count the total number of products sold and the total amount of money earned. I'm looking for the fields "count" and "total".

```
[
   {
      "id":1,
      "items":[
         {
            "offerName":"name_1",
            "count":6,
            "prices":[
               {
                  "costPerItem":129.0,
                  "total":774.0
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "offerName":"name_2",
            "count":1,
            "prices":[
               {
                  "costPerItem":120.0,
                  "total":120.0
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":2,
      "items":[
         {
            "offerName":"name_3",
            "count":10,
            "prices":[
               {
                  "costPerItem":30.0,
                  "total":300.0
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "offerName":"name_4",
            "count":1,
            "prices":[
               {
                  "costPerItem":10.0,
                  "total":10.0
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

I got the right values, but I think there is a way to make the calculation more beautiful, without a lot of looping.

```
counts = []
prices = []
for order in sales_data:
    products_list = order.get("items", [])
    for offer in products_list:
        counts.append(offer.get("count", 0))
        prices.append(offer.get("prices", []))
total_earned=[]
for price in prices:
    total = price[0].get("total", 0)
    total_earned.append(total)

print(sum(counts))
print(sum(total_earned))
```

Comment: For starters, if you don't need the actual list of numbers later, you can just add onto a numeric accumulator instead of appending onto a list and summing at the end. You can also combine your loops: instead of appending to `prices` and then looping again later, you can put that logic in the first loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For making the code as brief as possible, list comprehensions can be used.

I have come up with a solution with only 2 lines of logic.

I have defined the initial count and price as zero, and using list comprehension, I am updating the count and price for each item every iteration using the assignment operator `:=`

```
sales_data = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "items": [
            {
                "offerName": "name_1",
                "count": 6,
                "prices": [
                    {
                        "costPerItem": 129,
                        "total": 774
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "offerName": "name_2",
                "count": 1,
                "prices": [
                    {
                        "costPerItem": 120,
                        "total": 120
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "items": [
            {
                "offerName": "name_3",
                "count": 10,
                "prices": [
                    {
                        "costPerItem": 30,
                        "total": 300
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "offerName": "name_4",
                "count": 1,
                "prices": [
                    {
                        "costPerItem": 10,
                        "total": 10
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]


count, prices = 0, 0
[(count:=count+item['count'], prices:=prices+item['prices'][0]['total']) for sale in sales_data for item in sale['items']]

print('Count:', count, ', Prices:', prices)
```

This code outputs

```
Count: 18 , Prices: 1204
```

Answer (score 4):

You could potentially get each in a single (nested) iteration without having to build any intermediate data structures at all, like this:

```
print(sum(
    offer.get("count", 0)
    for order in sales_data
    for offer in order.get("items", [])
))  # 18

print(sum(
    price.get("total", 0)
    for order in sales_data
    for offer in order.get("items", [])
    for price in offer.get("prices", [])
))  # 1204.0
```

Or if you wanted to avoid duplicating the code for the first part of the loop, maybe the easy thing would be to first build a list out of the part you want to loop over in both cases (the offers) to make the sum expressions a little simpler:

```
offers = [offer for order in sales_data for offer in order.get("items", [])]

print(sum(
    offer.get("count", 0)
    for offer in offers
))  # 18

print(sum(
    price.get("total", 0)
    for offer in offers
    for price in offer.get("prices", [])
))  # 1204.0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can define an extraction method that pulls out the values you want from any given item, and apply it over the list:

```
extract = lambda item: (item['count'], item['prices'][0]['total'])
values = (extract(item) for order in sales_data for item in order['items'])
```

Then just sum things up element-wise to get your results:

```
counts, totals = map(sum, zip(*values))
print(counts)  # 18
print(totals)  # 1204.0
```